# Como puedo concatenar un array con un contador en laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, blade

hola necesito poder concatenar el indice de mi array en ciclo for... pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo

```
             @for($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++)
              <li>
                <input type="radio" id="radio_6" disabled name="product_radio" class="regular_radio radio_6">
                <label for="radio_6" style="background-color: {{$color['color2']}};"></label>
              </li>
              @endfor
```

En donde `{{$color['color'aqui_debo_concatenar_un_contador'']}}` debe estar concatenado a mi contador

de manera a que quede color0, color1, color2, color3 etc.. alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿El resultado final debe ser un texto `color1, color2, color3`?

Comment: si, exactamente ej: {{$color['color1']}}, {{$color['color2']}}, {{$color['color3']}}

Comment: No es lo mismo entonces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del `for` podrías utilizar `@php($aux = 'color' . $i)` y donde lo vayas a usar `$color[$aux]`

```
@for($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++)
    @php($aux = 'color' . $i)
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio_6" disabled name="product_radio" class="regular_radio radio_6">
        <label for="radio_6" style="background-color: {{$color[$aux]}};"></label>
    </li>
@endfor
```

Hay dos formas de usar `@php`

- Si solo usaras una linea, basta utilizar `@php(aqui_codigo_php)`, es decir, se coloca la directiva `@php` seguido de paréntesis que abre, el código php y por ultimo paréntesis de cierre.
- Si vas a agregar un bloque de código puedes usar `@php` para iniciar el bloque, seguido de las lineas de código **php** y para cerrar `@endphp`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#php

Comment: esto me funciono... gracias!